# ExactTarget API - Contracts Assembly Missing

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are starting to do development against the ET API and I am having trouble getting it set up.  In VS 2010, when I add the service reference and configure the web.config according to the documentation I get the following error.  I would really appreciate any help.

> Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'Contracts,
>   Version=9.0.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.    App_WebReferences/etAPI/

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to add the ET API to our website project but I was able to add it to a separate Class Library project and then call the methods from my website.  Consider this issue closed for me.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would you mind marking this as answered for the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't particular to ExactTarget - Visual Studio just doesn't know where the .dll is located. Likely solutions:

1. Add the assembly to your project's local \bin folder.
2. Add the assembly to the GAC

Comment: So it is a WCF assembly? I have having trouble determining what Contracts belongs to. The error only shows when I add a Service reference.

Comment: I missed that this was from adding a service reference. Usually `App_*` files are binaries that Visual Studio compiles from your projects, but that error indicates it isn't in the normal lookup paths. Is this in a separate project that you're including somewhere else? Can you find that .dll and copy it over to your project's bin folder?

Comment: This error is thrown by adding the Exact Target framework to my project. I am guessing there is a supporting assembly I am missing.

Service Reference
https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

I was following these instructions:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/connecting_to_the_web_service_api_using_wcf/

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas - I was going off my VS knowledge. I haven't used ET. Maybe step 7 if you modified the namespace?